# Is it possible to send email using Gmail account by Perl on a PC with only HTTP allowed?

Tags: perl, email, gmail

I've written a Perl program to send emails via Gmail account.

I use NET::SMTP, NET::SMTP::SSL and Authen::SASL modules. It can work well after I set the SMTP port to 465.

$smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new( 'smtp.gmail.com', Hello => 'localhost', Port => '465', Timeout => 30, Debug => 1 );

But in one of customer sites, the PC to run my program has only HTTP right to access Internet. So that the above line of code can't work any more. (I think SMTP needs the PC allowing socks.)
I've tried Mail::Webmail::Gmail, but it seems this module is too old, can't work any more.

I'd like to know in such a condition is it possible to send email just use web access in Perl, act like opening a web browser to login Gmail? 
Thank you!

Comment: You might consider a service like [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or http://elasticemail.com, which have a proper HTTPS-based API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just they are not free, this brings some trouble in commerce.

Comment: Any solution based on screen-scraping the gmail interface is likely to be (a) fragile and prone to break without warning whenever google change anything at their end and (b) probably against their terms of service. The services I suggested aren't free but they're pretty cheap - the starting rate for EE gives you 1250 emails for $1, I'd hope you can factor this into what you charge your customer.

Comment: To be even more blunt. If you're using Google's mail for commerce, you are basically stealing from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this while looking for a solution to a related problem.  I realize it is old, but has no answers and someone else may come across it.  Further, the comments are unnecessarily rude and unhelpful and make an assessment of the situation those commenting could not possibly be in a position to make.  It is quite reasonable to use GMail for commerce and in fact Google provides commercial email services and any such user might be using those.  So continue for a possible solution.

You could setup an external proxy that listens on port 80 and redirects that traffic to port 465 at Google.

I agree with the comments above regarding Google screen scraping.  I also agree on the possibility of using a third party service if it works within your use case.

With regard to the problem, if port 465 is blocked from sending then you will need to use a different port that is allowed to send.  As Google only listens on 25, 465 and 587 at smtp.gmail.com, you will need to use a proxy that will allow you to redirect requests made on an allowed port to one of the ports that Google is listening too.